# Are audio files in DocumentDirectory deleted when Core Data entity is deleted?

Tags: swift, core-data, entity, avfoundation

I'm recording audio with AVFoundation and saving the file in the DocumentDirectory. Then in Core Data the "sounds" entity stores the url as a string. Everything's working great. However I'm wondering: when sounds entities are deleted from Core Data how do to you delete the file from the DocumentDirectory ...or does that automagically happen?

My code to save to disk:

```
    let directoryURL = NSFileManager.defaultManager().URLsForDirectory(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask).first

    let audioFileName = NSUUID().UUIDString + ".m4a"
    let audioFileURL = directoryURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(audioFileName)

    // URL for Core Data store
    audioURL = audioFileName

    // Setup audio session

    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    do {
        try audioSession.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord, withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptions.DefaultToSpeaker)
    } catch _ {
        print("Error creating AVAudioSession")
    }

    let recordSettings = [AVFormatIDKey: NSNumber(unsignedInt: kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC), AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0, AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2]

    // Initiate and prepare recorder

    audioRecorder = try?AVAudioRecorder(URL: audioFileURL!, settings: recordSettings)
    audioRecorder?.delegate = self
    audioRecorder?.meteringEnabled = true
    audioRecorder?.prepareToRecord()
```

Thank you very much for any assistance! Sorry, I'm finding it a little difficult to track files in the document directory in the sim. (I'm in Swift 2.3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleting a Core Data instance will affect-- at most-- things in the Core Data store. Core Data doesn't know that the string you saved points to a file, so it doesn't try to do anything special with the string.

You can remove the file using the `removeItemAtURL:error:` method on `NSFileManager`. A good place to do this would be in your managed object subclass-- override `prepareForDeletion` and delete the file there.

Comment: ah fantastic thanks Tom! I'll try adding it to prepareForDeletion - that sounds like a clean approach + makes it much easier than I thought it might be (also given that "sounds" entity is a child of another core data entity).